# db2 How to use a variable in the select clause

Tags: variables, select, db2

How to use a variable in the select clause ?

I wish I could make the request

```
INSERT INTO tabLe1 (...) SELECT field, variable FROM table2;
```

but this request fails because of the variable

I tested this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;  --  works
```

But

```
DECLARE XX INTEGER;              --  works      
SET XX=1;                        --  works
SELECT XX FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; --  Does not work
```

How to use a variable in the DB2 select

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Typically variable declarations cannot be made outside a [compound SQL statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0053779.html). I don't know what you mean by "works" and "doesn't work", but certainly the client you use plays a role as well.

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  What client application?

Comment: This is to make a procedure

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in a select clause you can CREATE a global VARIABLE and then reference it in a SELECT. Here is an example

```
CREATE VARIABLE V INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
SELECT V FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

1          
-----------
          0

  1 record(s) selected.
```